# how to keep referance to an instance created on child thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a class, "myClass" with this code in the "main":

```
 ExecutorService service;  
 List<Future<Integer>> tasks = new ArrayList<Future<Integer>>();  
 service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numOfThreads);
```

Then I initiate each thread:

```
 for (int i = numOfThreads; i > 0; --i) {   
     tasks.add(service.submit(new StringSearcher(file, offset,threadChankSize, args[1],buffSize)));          
 }  
 for (Future<Integer> task : tasks) {         
    result += task.get();         
 }
```

The class has "_res" member that I need to get at the end of the program (after all threads terminated)
In order to do that I created a method "getRes" which returns "_res", but the problem is I don't have access to the class after it's thread has terminated.
is there a way to keep reference from "main" to the instance created in each thread?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just do this:

```
 List<StringSearcher> searchers = new ArrayList<StringSearcher>();

 for (int i = numOfThreads; i > 0; --i) {   
     StringSearcher task = new StringSearcher(file, offset,threadChankSize, args[1],buffSize);
     searchers.add(task);
     tasks.add(service.submit(task));          
 }  
 for (Future<Integer> task : tasks) {         
    result += task.get();         
 }
 for (StringSearcher searcher : searchers){
    /*do stuff with*/ searcher.getRes();
 }
```

Comment: Exactly. Object lifecycle has nothing to do with threads. It's all about where you keep references to them.